# Get attachment ID

Tags: php, wordpress, image, media

How do i get the "attachement_id="

like here ;
[image]

I hope someone can give me an answer. I want to tie this id to a jquery selector for fullscreen images.

Comment: show us how you're using this in your template

Comment: @S.Pols lol thanks -> http://www.hdwallpapersimages.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/01/Winter-Tiger-Wild-Cat-Images.jpg

Comment: @DannyHearnah that doesnt really matter does it? I just want to know how i can achieve that attachment ID as seen in the picture.

Comment: I do not have knowledge about wordpress, but if you can show your html we can maybe archieve this using jQuery.

Comment: Well.. this is the backend of wordpress and this is its media-library, so i did not use any html to achieve this image and link etc

Comment: From where are you trying to get the attachment id? From the frontend (i.e. javascript)? Backend (php)? What are you using it for?

Comment: I want to get the attachment id for the backend, to show it to the front end. so in Index.php (of wordpress) I want to get that damn ID to pass it into jquery in the index.php file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it this way;

```
foreach ($metas as $metakey) {
        $image_id++;

 echo "<div class='image' id='img_$image_id'>";
```

and for the jquery selector;

```
$('#img\\_<?php echo $image_id ?>').on('click', function () {
```

this way each image i click, actually is that image. So i got this

```
$full_image = wp_get_attachment_image_src($metakey['image'], 'full');

<script>
$('#img\\_<?php echo $image_id ?>').on('click', function () {
alert('<?php echo $full_image[0] ?>');
});
</script>
```

This results that each image i click i get the right url.

Thanks though.

Answer (score 0):

It is a little bit complicated, because all attachments are linked to the given posts.

**Example:** To display all of the images and titles attached to a certain page and display them as a list you can use the following:

```
 <?php if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();    

 $args = array(
   'post_type' => 'attachment',
   'numberposts' => -1,
   'post_status' => null,
   'post_parent' => $post->ID
  );

  $attachments = get_posts( $args );
     if ( $attachments ) {
        foreach ( $attachments as $attachment ) {

           echo wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment->ID, 'full' );
           echo '<br/>';
           echo apply_filters( 'the_title', $attachment->post_title );

          }
     }

 endwhile; endif; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you looking for is :

```
$attachment->ID
```

Take a look at the function `wp_get_attachment_image`

Reference: [Wordpress Attachment](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_attachment_image)

You have to get the `$post->ID` in order for that to work.

Reference : `https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.0.1/src/wp-includes/link-template.php#L392`

Comment: echo $attachment->;

doesnt do anything.